# How can I search books by seller using Product Advertising API?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

In product advertising API is there a way to search by seller. Previously using [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/ajax/searchResultsJson.html?currentPage=1&seller=1&useMYI=1) url

```
 https://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/ajax/searchResultsJson.html?currentPage=1&seller=1&useMYI=1
```

we used to search. But now this url no longer works. Is there a way or I have to search item and check seller? If there is no way in API , please suggest some better approach

Answer (score 0):

Well Amazon updated its product api. All API requests must be signed.

Here is a link to Amazon Product API documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html.

You can also try out the API here: http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html